# How to add suggetionbox in web when cursor is on button

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I want to show suggestion when cursor is on button or on some widget in flutter web

I share example how I want to show suggestion box but I don't know how to add suggestion box in flutter

[image]

Comment: can I use custom widget in tool tip

Comment: You can use child  to tooltip  for some widgets :   like this    Tooltip(message: "Hello World", child: new Text("foo"));

Comment: but I want to add container as tool tip and Tooltip widget has message property and it only accept string value

Comment: Tooltip(message: "Hello World", child:  Container ( child :Text("foo")) );  you can do like that

Comment: use tooltip `super_tooltip:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you. Used **`Tooltip`** Widget

Refer **`Tooltip`** [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)

Test below code [here](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true)

```
Tooltip(
  message: "Managers",
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text('OK'),
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: I want to add decoration and other icon in tt is it possible?

Comment: yes you can add decoration

Comment: like I want to add leading icon with it and I want to show tooltip left side of widget

Comment: wait I will try

Comment: also can I add horizontal offset in it?

Comment: I think **NO** you dont add horizontal offset in it documentaion says only `verticalOffset` are available

Comment: thanks for your answer I use margine to add horizontal space and it work

Comment: If you put `preferBelow: false,` and `margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 100),` tooltip shows top left try this. hope its help to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap widget with Tooltip see example.

[flutter tooltip example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)

Comment: but I want to use custom widget as tooltip this Tooltip widget only accept string as tip

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the tooltip related recommendations, if they don't quite meet your requirements, there's [OverlayEntry](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OverlayEntry-class.html) It allows to use any widget, but is not super easy to handle, so there's a couple packages out there that do some work with Overlays for you that you might consider.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_portal

https://pub.dev/packages/modals

To show overlay entry when hovering over some widget, wrap it with [MouseRegion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MouseRegion-class.html) and use its `onEnter` and `onExit` methods to show and hide overlay